# Accessing first element in Priority Queue c++

Tags: c++, constants, priority-queue, const-correctness

I am working on program in which I am require to use a priority queue. From my understanding the priority queue sorts the queue automatically from largest to smallest elements. I have create a simple priority queue of objects(nodes) that have a name and id number. I am trying to access the first object in the queue so I figured I could just use the "front" member function. This works when I use the standard queue but when I use a priority queue I get the error

> error: 'class std::priority_queue' has no member named 'front'

I tried using "top" as well but then I get the error

> error: passing 'const value_type (aka const node)' as 'this' argument
>   of 'void::display()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <queue>          

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    node(char n, int i) { name = n; id = i; }
    void display() { cout << "name: " << name << "   id : " << id << endl; }
    friend bool operator < (node a, node b) { return a.id < b.id; }
private:
    char name;
    int id;
};

int main()
{
  queue<node> myqueue; // Actually want a priority_queue<node>

  myqueue.push(node('a',5));
  myqueue.push(node('b',9));
  myqueue.push(node('c',7));

  myqueue.front().display(); // Error when using the type I want, even if I call top() instead
}
```

I will point out again that if I use queue instead of priority queue the code works. How do I access the front of a priority queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that `.display()` is not a constant member-function.
It should be:

```
void display() const { std::cout << "name: " << name << "   id : " << id << '\n';}
```

As an aside, only use `std::endl` if explicitly flushing might be neccessary, as it flushes all hope of good performance down the drain.

Also read: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `std::priority_queue::front` does not exist. We just can't invoke something doesn't exist.

Secondly, be const-correct. Declare your member functions `const`.

```
void display() const
{...}
```

This is because the return type of `std::priority_queue::top` is a const reference. Via a const reference (and const value), only const member functions can be used. Inside a const member function, the object cannot be modified, which is the meaning of being const.

Comment: Well, you get an upvote for writing more about const-correctness.

Answer (score 0):

std::priority_queue::front does not exist.
Use 
[`std::priority_queue::top`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/)

And yes, function display() should be const as mentioned by fellow member :)

```
void display() const { std::cout << "name: " << name << "   id : " << id << '\n';}
```

Comment: Happens to everyone. I clarified the question, but unless you see a way to add something else not already in other answers, keeping this won't be that useful...

Comment: Actually I missed the top part in question and found no one talking about that